# Want to multiply same matix n times using dot product

Tags: matrix, dot

I want to multiply same matrix using dot product for n times.

```
   U[n_]:=Apply[Dot,[MatrixExp[-I H ]],{i,0,n}]
```

Comment: Why not `MatrixExp[-I*H*n]` instead of multiplying explicitly?

Comment: That will not give same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Roman have mentioned.

```
H = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
n = 5;
Dot @@ Table[MatrixExp[-I*H], {i, n}] ==MatrixPower[MatrixExp[-I*H], n] == MatrixExp[-I*H*n] // Simplify
```

> `True`